# How can I count same values in JSON found in MYSQL column?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mysql-8.0

I am collecting JSON data in MYSQL column.
I want to count numbers with same keywords in this JSON data.

Example JSON column:

| id | column |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `{ "2": { "model": "Test Model" }, "3": { "model": "Test Model" } }` |
| 2 | `{ "4": { "model": "Test Model" }, "2": { "model": "Test Model" } }` |
| 3 | `{ "1": { "model": "Test Model" }, "4": { "model": "Test Model" } }` |
| 4 | `{ "2": { "model": "Test Model" } }` |

The output I want:

| key | count |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |

Can I do this easily and with shortcodes?

Mysql version: 8.0.27

Comment: Side note: The schema of the JSON looks pretty static to me. You should consider not to abuse JSON but use relational means like (lookup and/or linking) tables and columns instead. Then this would be a simple aggregation.

Comment: Mysql version: 8.0.27

Comment: While it's perfectly fine to store JSON records in a database, if you also find yourself needed to use SQL to look inside those records you will do **SO MUCH BETTER** to _also_ define real relational schema around the fields that matter. It is _so much more efficient_ to parse the JSON **once**, at insert/update time, rather than for _every single query_. You can also then use **indexes** on the fields, which is key for SQL performance. Again, you need don't need to extract and define relational fields for ALL of the JSON attributes... just what you will need to use with your queries later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```sql
SELECT jsontable.`key`, COUNT(*) `count`
FROM test
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(JSON_KEYS(test.json_value),
                      '$[*]' COLUMNS (`key` INT PATH '$')) jsontable
GROUP BY jsontable.`key`
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=717eeeacb3bceb45a2094e46d37c8865